# How to run easy_install and pip without root, without virtualenv?

Tags: linux, python, chroot, virtualenv

People have access to servers as normal users (jailed actually), and they're advised - at the moment - to download whatever python packages they need, `setup.py build` them, then add their location to `sys.path`.

Without virutalenv, is there a way to make easy_install and pip install packages to a directory (in `$PYTHONPATH`) inside of `~`?

Alternatively, can you set up a virtualenv that is always active for a given user, both in the shell and with repsect to Apache and mod_wsgi?

In short, how do you best get around the permissions problem in installing site packages?

Answer (score 1):

To get virtualenv available in shell automatically you should source its `bin/activate` script every time the user logs in. You can do this along with creating default virtualenv environment when the user is created. Or you can just add path to the virtualenv's python interpreter to the `$PATH` variable right in the user's `.bash_login`, `.zshrc` or whatever else.

Virtualenv, when activated, modifies two environment variables. First, it will add `{virtualenv}/bin` to your `$PATH`, and second, it will define `$VIRTUAL_ENV` variable telling where exactly virtualenv is set up. So you may try to mimic its behavior in Apache by setting these variables. In the end you should use virtualenv's python interpreter downloaded with virtualenv which has all necessary paths set up.

`mod_wsgi` in its hand has some configuration options which can help you with this. It should be sufficient to use [`WSGIPythonPath`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath). You might consider using [`WSGIPythonEggs`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonEggs) as well.

However note that you should protect the initial setup from being modified by user but accessible by user running apache.